# Horizontal Line before and after abstract, different alignment

Tags: lyx, vertical-alignment, article

I'm trying to set up a basic `.lyx` file for my lab reports. I'm now struggling with the abstract: I'd like to put before and after the abstract environment two horizontal lines. 
So, I did it graphically with Lyx `Insert -> Formatting -> Horizontal Line`, but the result is two lines that are slightly misaligned.

Here you have the `.tex` file exported from Lyx (as you can see I also rewrote the `\maketitle`command)

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{multicol} %Multicolumn
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} %Font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%Changing title left-aligned

\def\@maketitle{
{\LARGE\bfseries\@title\par}
\vspace{1.5em}
{\bfseries\@author\par}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Attempt}


\author{me}

\maketitle
\bigskip{}
\rule[0.5ex]{1\columnwidth}{1pt}
\begin{abstract}
\noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Suspendisse vel efficitur sem. Phasellus lorem ante, vestibulum ut
ornare a, mollis sed ante. Nam in dolor sit amet tortor mattis eleifend.
Etiam ut faucibus erat. Proin nibh lectus, aliquet eu nisi et, molestie
lacinia est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque erat urna,
consectetur eu elementum eget, tristique non quam.

\noindent Sed maximus varius felis. Etiam quis fermentum orci. Ut
sed pellentesque ipsum. Pellentesque justo magna, auctor id dolor
id, posuere aliquam nisi. Sed laoreet libero at tortor commodo, quis
bibendum tellus mattis. Aenean feugiat ligula eu gravida interdum.
Duis gravida lacus vitae dui dapibus, pellentesque tempor augue rutrum.
Nam eget massa in turpis viverra volutpat. Mauris tristique neque
est, eget luctus risus gravida a. Fusce ut ligula dolor. Sed bibendum
lacus enim, nec cursus metus pulvinar a. Duis dictum lacinia odio
quis ornare. Mauris vitae odio eget arcu gravida lacinia vel ac metus.
In volutpat eros mi, quis euismod lacus finibus vel.
\end{abstract}
\rule[0.5ex]{1\columnwidth}{1pt}

\begin{multicols}{2}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
vel efficitur sem. Phasellus lorem ante, vestibulum ut ornare a, mollis
sed ante. Nam in dolor sit amet tortor mattis eleifend. Etiam ut faucibus
erat. Proin nibh lectus, aliquet eu nisi et, molestie lacinia est.
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Pellentesque erat urna, consectetur
eu elementum eget, tristique non quam.

Sed maximus varius felis. Etiam quis fermentum orci. Ut sed pellentesque
ipsum. Pellentesque justo magna, auctor id dolor id, posuere aliquam
nisi. Sed laoreet libero at tortor commodo, quis bibendum tellus mattis.
Aenean feugiat ligula eu gravida interdum. Duis gravida lacus vitae
dui dapibus, pellentesque tempor augue rutrum. Nam eget massa in turpis
viverra volutpat. Mauris tristique neque est, eget luctus risus gravida
a. Fusce ut ligula dolor. Sed bibendum lacus enim, nec cursus metus
pulvinar a. Duis dictum lacinia odio quis ornare. Mauris vitae odio
eget arcu gravida lacinia vel ac metus. In volutpat eros mi, quis
euismod lacus finibus vel.

Sed vel lorem laoreet, posuere est in, ullamcorper dolor. Ut aliquet
metus porta neque sagittis dapibus. Mauris et eros tempus, volutpat
velit eget, maximus nisi. Maecenas porta tincidunt mi, vel vehicula
dolor tempus vel. Cras sit amet pulvinar lectus. Etiam eros ligula,
auctor vulputate tellus at, elementum sodales libero. Vivamus lorem
dui, maximus non hendrerit id, vestibulum quis velit. Sed vitae dolor
urna. Cras dui quam, luctus ut est eget, dictum dictum velit. Nam
eu lacinia turpis. Maecenas non tristique enim. Phasellus hendrerit
orci vel volutpat malesuada. Donec bibendum eget arcu vel gravida.
Curabitur suscipit et erat in consequat. Curabitur dignissim nisi
a dui auctor, id varius lacus hendrerit.

Fusce mattis lectus magna, eu tristique erat ullamcorper quis. Curabitur
massa est, hendrerit ac nibh et, posuere congue odio. Nunc efficitur
diam hendrerit finibus semper. Aliquam nec sem accumsan, volutpat
velit eget, venenatis mi. Aenean volutpat egestas elementum. Ut elementum
mauris ut lectus bibendum porttitor. Nunc venenatis tincidunt viverra.

Nullam venenatis hendrerit est. Nam lacinia feugiat purus, et laoreet
ex lacinia non. Vivamus at tellus id urna mattis iaculis. Nulla ac
vestibulum tortor. Aliquam luctus fringilla pharetra. Etiam sem justo,
euismod eget leo id, sodales ornare diam. Proin vehicula neque eget
metus vulputate luctus. Quisque dapibus imperdiet diam molestie fringilla.
Mauris sit amet sodales mi, eget malesuada ipsum. Aliquam lacus dolor,
vulputate dignissim consequat non, lacinia ac nisl. 

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule is indented with the standard paragraph indentation. Right click the line right next to the rule, select *Paragraph settings*, uncheck the box for *Indent paragraph*.